# Download Image from Input Stream display corrupted Image

Tags: android

This image display corrupted. It only happen once in awhile for all the downloading process. I need some recommendation to overcome and resolve this issue
[image]

```
 String fullUrl = ServerUrl + DomainConstantValues.IMAGE_LOCATION_POST + postImage.getPost_id() + "/" + postImage.getImage_path();
            Log.d("getReceveiver", "DownloadImagesPost: url " + fullUrl);
            //Download Image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(fullUrl).openStream();
            Log.d("getReceveiver", "DownloadImagesPost: " + input);
            //Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = CommonFunctions.readBitmapFromByte(input);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Log.d("getReceveiver", "DownloadImagesPost: ");
            }


 public static Bitmap readBitmapFromByte(InputStream input) {
    if (input != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return bitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Paste your downloading code here.

Comment: @TruongHieu I already put my code already